# Luks header overwritten with dd

Tags: dd, headers, luks, recovery

I've copy and pasted too fast from a tutorial and overwritten the LUKS header from one of my drives with dd. The used command was:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb bs=512 seek=1 count=100
```

And now:

```
cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdb
Device /dev/sdb is not a valid LUKS device.
```

Is there a possibilty to recover my header or is everything lost?

Installed OS is Debian 10 and unfortunately the disk was not encrypted when running dd and also no header backup is available :(

Comment: What do you mean by __"the disk was not encrypted when running dd"__? Was `sdb` a LUKS encrypted disk or not? If not, overwriting the 51200 bytes is bad, but a restore could be attempted. Also, it's interesting that you did not overwrite the start of the disk, but instead leave the first 512 bytes alone. See also [What does LUKS header contain?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/203675/20080).

Comment: Hi, i want to tell the disk is not unlocked via luks, i've read if the disk is unlocked the is a chance to recover.
I've read/done a tutorial to use a usb stick to unlock luks disks, and they suggest to leave first  512 bytes

Comment: It does make since that if the disk is unlocked, the keys are in RAM somewhere. However, if the disk is unlocked, you could just copy the contents to a safe location too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked:

> Is there a possibilty to recover my header or is everything lost ?

I'm really sorry, but the LUKS header contains the passphrase-encrypted key(s) which unlock everything else. Without a backup copy of the header, the data in unrecoverable. From `man cryptsetup`:

> **LUKS  header:**  If the header of a LUKS volume gets damaged, all data is permanently lost unless you have a header-backup.  If a key-slot is damaged, it can only be restored from a header-backup or if another  active key-slot with known passphrase is undamaged.  Damaging the LUKS header is something people manage to do with surprising frequency. This risk is the result of a trade-off between security and safety, as LUKS is designed for fast and secure wiping by just overwriting header and key-slot area.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, the content of your question has been asked here before and answered containing even more details.

https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=10765

:)

31.1.2021 13:14 German time:

This is a summary of what I had written in cgsecurity.org:

I asked the user if he had a copy of the LUKS header. He denied. I told him that the few seconds he ran the dd command were sufficient to erase the LUKS header which contains the necessary information to decipher the files.
He could not believe it telling me that he had a second stick set up the same way. I responded that the second stick contains a different key.

He thanked me and wished me a nice evening.
Then the same question came up here.

Basically this looks like a double posting - but not on this site :)

Comment: German Time is mine, i am from Germany and can't speak french, so this question was not written by me there ;)

Comment: So you complain the same question being asked again, but you also provide the same answer again. What's worse? ;-) A link to the question (inside stackexchange) would have been enough. If the question was asked "elsewhere", it's not really relevant.

Comment: @U. Windl Did you notice the other webpage is in French?